# Inverse Laplace Transform isn't A Contour Integral

Tags: signal-processing, laplace-transform

I've learned about and used the Laplace transform in several signal processing classes and the inverse transform has always been defined as an integral like this:

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\} = \frac{1}{2\pi j} \int_{\sigma_0 - j\infty}^{\sigma_0+j\infty} 
F(s)e^{st}ds \quad \quad \sigma_0 \in \text{ROC}$$

I'm now taking a supplementary class on functions of a complex variable, so I've been learning more about integration in the complex plane. I'm a bit confused as to how the above integral should be interpreted. Is it a contour integral along the line \$s = \sigma_0\$ parallel to the imaginary axis? Does using an integral with endpoints rather than along a defined contour imply that \$F(s)\$ has an antiderivative so the contour doesn't matter?